# Get url from Safari web content process

Tags: terminal, safari, command-line

Is there any way of getting the url of a safari process like activity monitor does:

```
dev-MacBook-Pro:~ dev$ ps ax | egrep '[c]om.apple.WebKit.WebContent.xpc'
42084   ??  Ss     0:00.32 /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know how this never received an answer. Extremely useful question!